# I want to be able to draw circles of different sizes

Tags: python, trigonometry

I have this code :

```
Cosinus = []
Sinus = []
Cosinus2 = []
Sinus2 = []
for Angle in range(1,360):
    Radiann = Angle * 3.14159 / 180
    Cosinus.append(math.cos(Radiann))
    Sinus.append(math.cos(Radiann))
    for Radius in range(1,20):
        Cosinus2.append(Cosinus[Radius] * Radius)
        Sinus2.append(Sinus[Radius] * Radius)
```

Obviously, I have many errors (I am not sure my code will do what I want):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/louistremblay/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 53, in <module>
    Cosinus2.append(Cosinus[Radius] * Radius)
IndexError: list index out of range
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to have a 20 X 360 matrix (or array ?) that will show cosinus values for each angle (from 1 to 360 degrees).

So first line will be a radius of 1, second line a radius of 2, ...

Same thing for sinus values.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it would be nice if you could spare time to take a [tour] and learn [ask]. anyway, given you are asking for [tag:python] please add the relevant tag.

Comment: I assume you are looking for a 40 x 360 array not a 20 x 360 array that shows Sin and Cosine of Angles from 0 to 359 degrees for Radii from 0 ton 19?

Comment: Those are some very misleading variable names. `Cosinus2` and `Sinus2` look like they contain adjacent and opposite side lengths, not cosines or sines.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a pair of arrays which contain a row for each set of radii from 1 to 20 I would do it as follows:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos   # make use of math library functions
import numpy as np                   # Utilize numpy array features

#Build Arrays for Rad=1 Row
SinM = np.array([sin(radians(d)) for d in range(360)])  
CosM = np.array([sin(radians(d)) for d in range(360)])

# Build Baseline Arrays
sa = np.array([sin(radians(d)) for d in range(360)])
ca = np.array([cos(radians(d)) for d in range(360)])
for rad in range(2, 4):
    SinM = np.vstack((SinM, sa*rad))
    CosM = np.vstack((CosM, ca* rad))
```

This gives you two 20 x 360 Arrays SinM & CosM which each contain rows for the product of Sin & Cos * radii from 1 to 20.